# Add new action row to Woocommerce Attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wondered if someone could help with the following?

I want to add a new action into the attributes table (WooCommerce -> Attributes -> Configure Terms)

Currently there are when you hover over the attribute there is Edit | Quick Edit | Delete | View

I would like to add to this.

I know you can use the following example code in functions.php to add to the pages table, but I don't know how to add this into the Woocommerce table?

I've added it into the woocommerce-admin-functions.php but can't get it to work.

```
 function search_google($actions, $page_object)
{
   $actions['google_link'] = '<a href="http://google.com/search?q=' . $page_object->post_title . '" class="google_link">' . __('Search Google for Page Title') . '</a>';

   return $actions;
}

add_filter('page_row_actions', 'search_google', 10, 2);
```

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You most likely are searching for 'tag_row_actions' or "{$taxonomy}_row_actions".

You can see them in here [class-wp-terms-list-table.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php#L265)